# Getting the class name from within the initialize method when class inherited from Hash

Tags: ruby, introspection

I have a class that inherits from `Hash`. When this class itself gets inherited from, I want to know the class name of the inheriting class from within the `initialize` method. When I call `self` I get `{}`, which doesn't know of the `name` method.

```
class Foo < Hash
  def initialize
    # Here i want to know that the class is Foo
  end
end
```

How do I get the class name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s very simple: `self.class.name`

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Brockman's answer will return you the string if you want to do a check:

```
if self.kind_of?(Foo)
  #whatever you want
end
```

The thing is due to the intent of the initializer, when you call Foo.new the instance will always be an instance of the class Foo or child, so I'm confused about what you're trying to do.